# Tuning parameters in a neural network with sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, hyperparameters, mlp

### Background

I am trying to make a relation between one `df` column and another. So if we assume the columns are named `x`,`y` respectively, what I need is a relation `f(x)=y`.
I tried using linear regression like so:

```
model = Pipeline([('poly', PolynomialFeatures(degree=deg)),
                      ('linear', LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False))])
```

and iterating over `deg` with a `for` loop, I found out that the best value is `deg=9` (even though for `deg=3` the results are close) where

```
MSE: 7.282878279669111    MAE: 1.704843791514593
```

---

### The problem

Now I am trying to create a neural network (Here I'm using `MLPRegressor`) but unsure of what parameters to choose. I tried changing parameters by hand and sometimes got good results of `mse~7.1` and sometimes got terrible result like `mse~20`. I got better results after switching from `relu` to `logistic`, and played a bit with the # of layers and nodes in each layer.

My question is how can I efficiently and automatically search for the best **hyperparameters**, including the **layer architecture** (# of layers and # of nodes in each layer) and the **degree of polynomial features**. So far the code I have is:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_train_norm = scaler.fit_transform(X_train.values.reshape(-1, 1))
X_test_norm = scaler.fit_transform(X_test.values.reshape(-1, 1))

model = Pipeline([('poly', PolynomialFeatures(degree=deg)),
                ('mlpr', MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(deg, 6, 8, 1),
                                      activation='relu',
                                      solver='adam', max_iter=10000))])
```

---

I did find out that for a random forest you can use

```
rf_random = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=rf,
                               param_distributions=random_grid,
                               n_iter=100, cv=3, verbose=2,
                               random_state=42, n_jobs=-1)
```

But I wasn't able to implement a search like this one in the case of a neural network.

Comment: Take a look at sklearn's [grid search](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html). Edit: A more [in-depth](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html) explanation.

Comment: There's literally the -almost- same question in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61163759/tuning-mlpregressor-hyper-parameters
Do some research beforehand, it helps keeping the place clean and lean :)

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr Hi! How can I use this to change the degree as well?

Comment: @AleixCC I came across that question, but it did not show how to control the degree in the pipeline

Comment: @ArielYael Take a look at this [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/grid_search_text_feature_extraction.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-grid-search-text-feature-extraction-py). They also use a pipeline and they control their grid search by using the following pattern `<model_label>__<parameter>`. Therefore, in your case, it would be `poly__degree`.